# Perl issue with % character

Tags: perl, character

I am writing a script where i would be running a command on bash shell and printing out the result.
I would read from a file A.txt

A.txt

```
AAA:BBB
CCC:DDD
AAA:FFF
```

MyCode

```
my $file = /path/to/A.txt;
open(my $fh, '<', $file)
 or die "Couldn't open file";

while (my $line = <$fh>){
 my ($ins,$pre) = split /:/, $line;

 if ((substr $ins,0,1) eq "A"){
  $mo = "A/C/$ins";
 }
 elsif ((substr $ins,0,1) eq "C"){
  $mo = "X/Y/$ins";
 }

 Env::modulecmd:load($mo);
 print "Running command cat $pre\%";
 $result = `cat '$pre'\% | head`;
 Env:modulecmd:unload($mo);
 print $result;
}

close $fh;
```

I am facing a strange issue, the print command only works right for the last line, for the rest it prints the '%' character in the next line, but for the last line it works exactly as expected.

So as a result the $result variable is only rightfully evaluated for the last line of A.txt and the rest of 2 lines doesn't give any output.

Can anyone please suggest what am i doing wrong here.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't removing the line endings. Normally, the following would do:

```
chomp($line);
```

However, you are reading a Windows text file (lines ending with CRLF) on a unix system (lines ending with LF). Either convert the file (e.g. using `dos2unix`), or use the following instead of `chomp`:

```
$line =~ s/\s+\z//;
```